# how to stop the setinterval function in javascript without button

Tags: javascript, excel

I am reading Excel file via javascript ..

```
<button onclick="myStopFunction()">Stop Meter</button>
        var myVar=setInterval(function(){readdata(1,2)},2000);
function myStopFunction()
{
    clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

code for reading excel file

```
var xVal = 1;
var yVal = 2

    function readdata(x,y) {
        x = xVal;
        y = yVal;
        try {
            var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
            excel.Visible = false;
            var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("D:\\Test1.xls");// alert(excel_file.worksheets.count);
            var excel_sheet = excel_file.Worksheets("Sheet1");
            var data = excel_sheet.Cells(x, y).Value;
            //alert(data);
            drawWithexcelValue(data);

            xVal = xVal + 1;

            excel.Application.Quit();
        }

        catch (ex) {
            alert(ex);
        }
    }
```

Now i want to rid off from the stop meter in such a way that when the excel value gets blank or null it will get exit ..how to do this
i have tried some thing like this

```
 if(xVal==null& xVal=="")
    {
    clearInterval(myVar);
    }
```

but i did not get success

Comment: Don't try to put code in comments, edit your question and show what you tried.

Comment: You can call `clearInterval()` from the `readdata()` function.

Comment: Or call `myStopFunction()` from `readdata()`, since it already knows which interval to clear.

Comment: how ?? can you give me a code

Comment: i tried this but it won't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
xVal = xVal + 1;
if (data === null || data === '') {
   myStopFunction();
}
excel.Application.Quit();
```

I.e. add the `if(){}` between `xVal...` and `excel...` lines.

Actually it looks like you need to check, if there's a value in `data` before `drawWithexcelValue(data);` line, unless you don't want to "draw" an empty/null value too.

Comment: if(data==null || data=="")
{
 myStopFunction();
}
this worked..:D...thanx for helping me guys and for giving me your precious time

Comment: Rather just like in my code (`===`), just in case there's `0` in `data`, which I suppose is an acceptable value. If it's not, you can use `==`.

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
if(xVal==null || xVal=="")
{
    clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

`&` is `binary AND`, you want `boolean OR`, which is `||`.

Comment: it keeps running .it is not exiting

Comment: You should be checking something that comes from Excel, since `xVal` is simply incremented by your code.